# How to use cmake and vcpkg to import GLAD/GLFW3/ImGUI libraries on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, vcpkg, glad

My goal is to write a simple, portable application using ImGUI. I also want a platform-agnostic build experience using cmake, and vcpkg to install dependencies. I got the program built and running on my Windows machine, but it's failing on my Macbook (macOS Monterey 12.6).

This is my vcpkg.json:

```json
{
    "name": "imguitest",
    "version": "1.0",
    "dependencies": [
        "glad",
        "glfw3",
        {
            "name": "imgui",
            "features": [ "glfw-binding", "opengl3-binding" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.23)

project(ImGui-Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp
)

find_package(glad CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE glad::glad)

find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE glfw)

find_package(imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE imgui::imgui)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE OpenGL::GL)
```

After running this:

```bash
# export VCPKG_DIR=/path/to/vcpkg/repo/
cmake -B ./build -S . "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_DIR/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glad" with any of
  the following names:

    gladConfig.cmake
    glad-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "glad" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glad_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glad"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Do I have to manually install GLAD package myself and set the path? I thought vcpkg would handle that for me. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something, as I'm new to modern cmake and vcpkg.

Comment: As glad is the first library you're looking for I'm guessing that vcpkg is not working at all. I've not used vcpkg myself but I'd check that the toolchain file is loading, the packages are installed etc.

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks, after some investigation in the build logs I found the missing dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it: `brew install pkg-config`

I got more descriptive error messages after I deleted the `build` folder. This error message was hidden when configuring cmake with vscode, but was visible when doing it through zsh terminal.

```
Building glfw3[core]:arm64-osx...
warning: -- Using community triplet arm64-osx. This triplet configuration is not guaranteed to succeed.
-- [COMMUNITY] Loading triplet configuration from: /Users/munta/Dev/vcpkg/triplets/community/arm64-osx.cmake
-- Downloading https://github.com/glfw/glfw/archive/7482de6071d21db77a7236155da44c172a7f6c9e.tar.gz -> glfw-glfw-7482de6071d21db77a7236155da44c172a7f6c9e.tar.gz...
-- Extracting source /Users/munta/Dev/vcpkg/downloads/glfw-glfw-7482de6071d21db77a7236155da44c172a7f6c9e.tar.gz
-- Using source at /Users/munta/Dev/vcpkg/buildtrees/glfw3/src/172a7f6c9e-7678776297.clean
GLFW3 currently requires the following libraries from the system package manager:
    xinerama
    xcursor
    xorg
    libglu1-mesa
    pkg-config

These can be installed via brew install libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev pkg-config
-- Configuring arm64-osx
-- Building arm64-osx-dbg
-- Building arm64-osx-rel
-- Fixing pkgconfig file: /Users/munta/Dev/vcpkg/packages/glfw3_arm64-osx/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_find_acquire_program.cmake:619 (message):
  Could not find pkg-config.  Please install it via your package manager:

      brew install pkg-config
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_fixup_pkgconfig.cmake:151 (vcpkg_find_acquire_program)
  ports/glfw3/portfile.cmake:43 (vcpkg_fixup_pkgconfig)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)
```